# Why would $_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I have WampServer 2 installed on my Windows 7 computer. I'm using Apache 2.2.11 and PHP 5.2.11. When I attempt to upload any file from a form, it seems to upload, but in PHP, the `$_FILES` array is empty. There is no file in the `c:\wamp\tmp` folder. I have configured `php.ini` to allow file uploads and such. The `tmp` folder has read/write privileges for the current user. I'm stumped.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="vanilla-upload.php" method="POST">
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
echo 'file count=', count($_FILES),"\n";
var_dump($_FILES);
echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I'm sure there something dumb that you're overlooking. For example, are you sure to have the code in `vanilla-upload.php`?

Comment: Ha I was having the same problem. I checked the error logs and it said that a file was being uploaded that exceeded the maximum allowed size.

Comment: Ha, my `<input>` had no `name=` :D

Comment: I tried to upload a file not from root, but with a script that was located in a "subfolder", like this: www.something.com\somthing_\something.php. $_FILE was empty! I tried the same code from www.something.com - and it worked... no clue how to solve this.. I did workaround.

Comment: I dont belive I lose hours just because the input(s) had no name... thanks @Fanky

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you everybody for the vary comprehensive replies. Those are all very helpful. The answer turned out to be something very odd. It turns out that PHP 5.2.11 doesn't like the following:

```
post_max_size = 2G
```

or

```
post_max_size = 2048M
```

If I change it to `2047M`, the upload works.

Comment: Note that such a high value is an vulnerability to out-of-space/ddos attacks. Just adding this so people are aware its too much, when they try to copy&paste your solution. Anyways, 2 gigs would require an upload time that is way too long.

Comment: Not too large any more. We have clients who upload files in the 1-3G range quite regularly. Since they are uploading files onto their own servers, and they are IP whitelisted servers, the exchange is quite normal and merely a way to allow a client to use their equipment the way they want to use it. They pay the bills, no security risk involved, no problems.

Answer (score 584):

**Here's a check-list for file uploading in PHP:**

1. Check php.ini for:
   `file_uploads = On`
   `post_max_size = 100M`
   `upload_max_filesize = 100M`

- You might need to use `.htaccess` or `.user.ini` if you are on shared hosting and don't have access to `php.ini`.
- Make sure
  you’re editing the correct ini file –
  use the `phpinfo()` function to verify your
  settings are actually being applied.
- Also make sure you don’t
  misspell the sizes - it should be `100M` *not* `100MB`.

2. Make sure your `<form>` tag has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. No other tag will work, it has to be your FORM tag. Double check that it is *spelled correctly*. Double check that multipart/form-data is surrounded by STRAIGHT QUOTES, not smart quotes pasted in from Word OR from a website blog (WordPress converts straight quotes to angle quotes!). If you have multiple forms on the page, make sure they both have this attribute. Type them in manually, or try straight single quotes typed in manually.
3. Make sure you do not have two input file fields with the same `name` attribute.  If you need to support multiple, put square brackets at the end of the name:

   ```
   <input type="file" name="files[]">
   <input type="file" name="files[]">
   ```
4. Make sure your tmp and upload directories have the correct read+write permissions set.  The temporary upload folder is specified in PHP settings as `upload_tmp_dir`.
5. Make sure your file destination and tmp/upload directories do not
   have spaces in them.
6. Make sure all `<form>`'s on your page have `</form>` close tags.
7. Make sure your FORM tag has `method="POST"`. GET requests do not support multipart/form-data uploads.
8. Make sure your file input tag has a NAME attribute. An ID attribute is NOT sufficient! ID attributes are for use in the DOM, not for POST payloads.
9. Make sure you are not using Javascript to disable your `<input type="file">` field on submission
10. Make sure you're not nesting forms like `<form><form></form></form>`
11. Check your HTML structure for invalid/overlapping tags like `<div><form></div></form>`
12. Also make sure that the file you are uploading does not have any non-alphanumeric characters in it.
13. Once, I just spent hours trying to figure out why this was happening to me all of a sudden. It turned out that I had modified some of the PHP settings in `.htaccess`, and one of them (not sure which yet) was causing the upload to fail and `$_FILES` to be empty.
14. You could potentially try avoiding underscores (`_`) in the `name=""` attribute of the `<input>` tag
15. Try uploading very small files to narrow down whether it's a file-size issue.
16. Check your available disk space. Although very rare, it is mentioned in this [PHP Manual page comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php#46257):

    > If the $_FILES array suddenly goes mysteriously empty, even though your form seems correct, you should check the disk space available for your temporary folder partition. In my installation, all file uploads failed without warning. After much gnashing of teeth, I tried freeing up additional space, after which file uploads suddenly worked again.
17. Be sure that you're not submitting the form through an AJAX POST request instead of a normal POST request that causes a page to reload. I went through each and every point in the list above, and finally found out that the reason due to which my $_FILES variable was empty was that I was submitting the form using an AJAX POST request. I know that there are methods to upload files using ajax too, but this could be a valid reason why your $_FILES array is empty.

*Source for some of these points:

https://web.archive.org/web/20050426084124/http://getluky.net/2004/10/04/apachephp-_files-array-mysteriously-empty/*

Comment: This doesn't apply to the discussion starter, but I had hosting provider who had their firewall policy too strict which caused some uploads to fail.

Comment: Maybe the "accepted" answer solved the original post, but this answer is the one that I found most helpful. When in doubt, look at the source as seen by the browser. Checking off each item in this list and tracing backward, I found my error in a most unexpected place. If you're struggling with a similar problem, believe me, it's probably not a bug in Apache. ;)

Comment: Also make sure your form element containing the file input is NOT a child of another form element. e.g. `<form><form><input type="file"></form></form>`

Comment: wow! thank you for this list. my problem was #2. i was calling `$('#my-form')[0].reset();` in the submit handler.

Comment: I'd add that certain Suhosin configurations can throw uploads off, and I'm not convinced that "_" in an upload field is a cause for concern. Otherwise, thanks for the exhaustive answer! Good reference.

Comment: Another point : replacing `<input type="file" name="foo"` with `<input type="file" name="foo[]"`

Comment: thanks. in my case number 7 . enctype="multipart/form-data" was the culprit.

Comment: Some of these are from an article here: http://getluky.net/2004/10/04/apachephp-_files-array-mysteriously-empty/ copy and pasted without attribution

Comment: Also check that this php.ini key is set, if it is blank it will result in a blank $_FILES object:
        `upload_tmp_dir="/path/to/tmp/dir/"`

Comment: #8 was the one that hit me! I thought files only needed IDs, not names!

Comment: In my situation - where I had to enable cross domain uploading - I had to add "cache-control" to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Comment: Make sure all attributes are enclosed properly within quotes. In my case the form worked well, but $_FILES was still empty, because I missed a quote in the form.

Comment: what if i have all steps in place and it uploads the file but at some company places the $_files stays empty.. How to debug this one?

Comment: Also, check php.ini for enable_post_data_reading=On , because "Disabling this option causes $_POST and $_FILES not to be populated." (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading)

Comment: I had to start my local Xampp for Windows with administration rights ...guess thats #4, but just in case someone is looking for this

Comment: "enctype="multipart/form-data", why is this bit mandatory ? anyways solved the issue for me thanks

Comment: One more thing to the list if you are using php-fpm:
 - Once you change values in /etc/php.ini you must restart php-fpm service in order to take the new values -> systemctl restart php-fpm
 - An just in case also restart you httpd service -> systemctl restart httpd

Comment: @sudee thanks dude! mine is not working because my input file is inside a div tag, it works after i remove the div and move the input file tag directly inside the form tag

Comment: This link solved my requirement. 

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-php-maximum-upload-file-size-in-an-htaccess-file

I added the following to my htaccess as suggested.

`php_value upload_max_filesize nnM` and `php_value post_max_size nnM`

Answer (score 83):

As far as the HTML you appear to have set that part up correctly. You already have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which is very important to have on the form.

As far as your `php.ini` setup, sometimes on systems multiple `php.ini` files exist. Be sure you are editing the correct one. I know you said you have configured your `php.ini` file to have file uploads, but did you also set your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to be larger than the file you are trying to upload? So you should have:

```
file_uploads = On; sounds like you already did this
post_max_size = 8M; change this higher if needed
upload_max_filesize = 8M; change this higher if needed
```

Does your directory: `"c:\wamp\tmp"` have both read and write permissions? Did you remember to restart Apache after you made the `php.ini` changes?

---

Comment: +1: For restarting Apache server tip. Many Windows users forget that.

Answer (score 44):

It is important to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form, example

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

I have a same problem looking 2 hours ,is very simple to we check our server configuration first.

**Example:**

```
echo $upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');  
echo $post_max_size=ini_get('post_max_size');
```

any type of file size is `:20mb`, but our `upload_max_size` is above `20mb` but array is `null`. Answer is our `post_max_size` should be greater than  `upload_max_filesize`

```
post_max_size = 750M  
upload_max_filesize = 750M
```

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your input element has a 'name' attribute.
`<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" />`

If this is missing the $_FILES will be empty.

Answer (score 6):

Here another cause I found: 
When using JQuery Mobile and the form attribute data-ajax is set to true, the FILES array will be empty. So set data-ajax to false.

Answer (score 6):

No one mentioned this but it helped me out and not many places on the net mention it.

Make sure your php.ini sets the following key:

```
    upload_tmp_dir="/path/to/some/tmp/folder"
```

You'll need to check with your webhost if they want you to use an absolute server file path.  You should be able to see other directory examples in your php.ini file to determine this.  As soon as I set it I got values in my _FILES object.

Finally make sure that your tmp folder and wherever you are moving files to have the correct permissions so that they can be read and written to.

Comment: This fixed my problem. In my case the temp directory was in C drive and it looks like XAMPP didn't have permission to write in C drive. I changed the temp dir to some folder in D drive and that worked.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the same problem and testing everything, not getting error reporting and nothing seemed to be wrong.
I had error_reporting(E_ALL) 
But suddenly I realized that I had not checked the apache log and voilà!
There was a syntax error on the script...! (a missing "}" )

So, even though this is something evident to be checked, it can be forgotten...
In my case (linux) it is at:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your php.ini for *enable_post_data_reading=On* , because:

> Disabling this option **causes $_POST and $_FILES not to be populated**. The only way to read postdata will then be through the php://input stream wrapper. (... )

In http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to upload an array of files then you may need to increase [`max_file_uploads`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) in `php.ini` which is by default set to `20`

**Note**: `max_file_uploads` can NOT be changed outside php.ini. See [PHP "Bug" #50684](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50684&edit=1)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible culprit is apache redirects.  In my case I had apache's httpd.conf set up to redirect certain pages on our site to http versions, and other pages to https versions of the page, if they weren't already.  The page on which I had a form with a file input was one of the pages configured to force ssl, but the page designated as the action of the form was configured to be http.  So the page would submit the upload to the ssl version of the action page, but apache was redirecting it to the http version of the page and the post data, including the uploaded file was lost.

Answer (score 2):

If your main script is `http://Some_long_URL/index.php` be carefull to specify the full URL (with explicit `index.php` and **not** only `http://Some_long_URL`) in the `action` field. Surprisingly, if not, the right script is executed, but with en empty $_FILES !

Comment: Do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

### Do not trust the temp folder location provided by `sys_get_temp_dir` if you're in a shared hosting environment.

Here is one more thing to check that has not yet been mentioned...

I assumed, naturally, that the folder where my PHP script stored temporary file uploads was `/tmp`. This belief was reinforced by the fact that `echo sys_get_temp_dir() . PHP_EOL;` returns`/tmp`. Also, `echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');` returns nothing.

To verify that the uploaded file does in fact briefly appear in my `/tmp` folder, I added a `sleep(30);` statement to my script (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48941426/8840617)) and navigated to my `/tmp` folder in cPanel File Manager to locate the file. However, no matter what, the uploaded file was nowhere to be found there.

I spent hours trying to determine the reason for this, and implemented every suggestion that's been offered here.

Finally, after searching my website files for the query `tmp`, I discovered that my site contained other folders named `tmp` in different directories. I realized that **my PHP script was actually writing the uploaded files to `.cagefs/tmp`.** (The *"Show Hidden Files"* setting must be enabled in cPanel in order to view this folder.)

So, why does the `sys_get_temp_dir` function return inaccurate info?

Here's an explanation from the PHP.net webpage for [`sys_get_temp_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) (i.e., the top comment):

> If running on a Linux system where systemd has PrivateTmp=true (which
>   is the default on CentOS 7 and perhaps other newer distros), this
>   function will simply return "/tmp", not the true, much longer,
>   somewhat dynamic path.

This SO post delves into the issue, as well:

- [Stack Overflow: *sys_get_temp_dir in shared hosting environment*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13186069/8840617)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found that it was my IDE was part of the issue.  I was launching the debugger directly from the IDE (PHPStorm) instead of just using the browser directly. The IDE spawned URL was like this:

```
"...localhost:63342/CB_Upload/index.php?_ijt=j2hcbacqepj87bvg66ncuohvne"
```

and just using:

```
"...localhost/CB_Upload/index.php"
```

worked just fine.   My set up is PC / Windows 10 / WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 64bit

Comment: same thing here, i was running in circles for an hour so far ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and none of theme was my error. Check in your .htaccess file, if you got one, if "MultiViews" are enabled. I had to disable them.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the issue was in wrong value in htaccess as shamittomar mentioned.

Change `php_value post_max_size 10MB` to `php_value post_max_size 10M`

Answer (score 0):

I was empty `$_FILES` because after `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` i placed

```
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Initial code was like

```
<span class="span_left">Photos (gif/jpg/jpeg/png) </span>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="upload_file" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload photo" />
</form>
```

I decided to modify and

```
<div>
<span class="span_left">Photos (gif/jpg/jpeg/png) </span>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="upload_file" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload photo" />
</form>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

So conclusion is that after `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` must be `<input name, type, id` and must not be `<div>` or some other tags

In my situation correct code was

```
<div>
<span class="span_left">Photos (gif/jpg/jpeg/png) </span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="upload_file" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload photo" />
</form>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems with $_FILES empty. The above check-list do not mention MultiViews in .htaccess, httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf.

If you have MultiViews set in the options directive for your directory containing the web site, $_FILES will be empty, even though Content-Length header if showing that the file i uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery Mobile

Using a multipart form with a file input is not supported by Ajax. In this case you should decorate the parent form with data-ajax="false" to ensure the form is submitted properly to the server.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-ajax="false">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detach your form form the page you-re using
into a simple php page that has the form and
php code only, and test it like that.

Any bootstrap or java script might clean out
the _FILES[]. That was my case

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX instead of a Form submission, then ensure the request header `Content-Type` is set to `multipart/form-data; boundary=myAwesomeBoundary'` where `myAwesomeBoundary` is the unique string that separates the request body parts. I made the mistake of overriding the `Content-Type` header by setting it to only `multipart/form-data` without setting the `boundary`. The fix was to not override the header but let the browser generate it for me.