# Empty $_FILES and $_POST when uploading big files

Tags: php, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would $_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

I am trying to upload files that are big up to 15 Megabytes.
My PHP configuration in `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

and in PHP with `ini_get()` and `phpinfo()` I saw the right value `20M`.
But when I try to upload 10 MB file it returns empty `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays.
I checked the `$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]` variable and it returns me `10671561` (10.4MB), which is smaller than the `20M` config value.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess code is correct. You can try below code in your php file then try it.

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '20M' );
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');  
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Let me know if not working.

Comment: which place you have set my code?

Comment: in the constructor of the controller

Comment: which framework you have to use?

Comment: because i have already use above to code in cakephp and CodeIgniter. and code perfectly working.

Comment: thanks, it worked on the global space....

Answer (score 0):

Is your server configured to use .htaccess files? If you're using Apache, you should check your virtual host config (e.g., /etc/apache2/sites-available/<your site>) and make sure that `AllowOverride All` is set.

Comment: if i saw my htaccess values in phpinfo(), its not tells that this is overided?