# Move_uploaded_file() function is not working

Tags: php, file

I'm working on a website and I want the user to be able to upload files. So I'm trying to learn how to do that. I researched and it said that I had to use the function move_uploaded_file(). I wrote the code just like it was on the example (changing the data), but it wouldn't work. Please help me, I'm new at these. Here's what I've done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
   <form action="upload_file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
      <input type="file"name="file">
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</body>
<html>
```

This is the upload_file.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <head>
     <body>
        <?php
          $move = "/Users/George/Desktop/uploads/";
          echo $_FILES["file"]['name']."<br>";
          echo $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']."<br>";
          echo $_FILES["file"]['size']."<br>";
          echo $_FILES['file']['error']."<br>";
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $move);
        ?>
     <body>
<html>
```

Comment: The solution everybody is posting on the manual, did you check there? http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: What are Directory permissions for `/Users/George/Desktop/uploads/`? That has to be writeable

Comment: I don't know what Directory Permissions is. Can you explain?

Comment: Are you running this website on linux or on windows?

Comment: I found the error ($move = "/Users/George/Desktop/uploads/"_.$_FILENAME['file']['name']_;). It works now. Thankyou!

Comment: Slightly concerned max size seems to be controlled by the client

Comment: Make the target dir `777` or, make it owned by your web server's user, (e.g on ubuntu's ngnix it's `www-data`).

Answer (score 69):

1. [Enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) PHP **error reporting** in order to see the error message from `move_uploaded_file()` that explains the problem.
2. Check the `$_FILES['image']['error']` [variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

In your case it's a wrong filename. The file will be stored in a temporary location, so use `tmp_name` instead of `name`:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/../../uploads/'. $_FILES["image"]['name']);
// echo "Uploaded";
```

Comment: You should also check for return value of the function. What about directory permissions for your destination?

Comment: Don't use the given file name directly to store the upload files onto your file system. At least sanitize it.

Comment: Just to add to the comment by @Ja͢ck, you should also pass the name though basename(), as while PHP protects you at the moment, it's done for compatibility with Internet Explorer. In the future, if that was to be removed, then Evil Hacker ™ could do `curl -F 'file=@example.php;filename=../../../example.php'
https://example.com/upload/`

Comment: @CraigFrancis Removing the basename operation from the engine would violate RFC 7578, so I've updated that portion of the code to enforce this idea. Additionally, there's an [engine test](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/tests/basic/rfc1867_max_file_size.phpt#L24) on it to ensure that it won't be arbitrarily removed from the engine.

Answer (score 30):

Try using `copy()` function instead of `move_uploaded_file()`. It **worked** for me.

```
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
```

Comment: This answer must be deleted.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why? It would be useful to read the reasoning (I'm not disagreeing)

Comment: you will have a tmp folder full of unused files. if you are uploading multiple and big files you will be in trouble

Answer (score 22):

This is a working example.

**HTML Form :**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php        
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$move = "/Users/George/Desktop/uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

That's one.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $move);
```

That's two.

Check if the `uploads` dir is writeable

That's three.

**Return Values**

> Returns TRUE on success.
>
> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
>   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

Look at return value of the function.

That's it.

Comment: Check if the uploads dir is writeable (very nice !)

Answer (score 6):

maybe you need to grant more permissions to your files.

suppose your code are under /var/www/my_project

try `chmod -R 777 /var/www/my_project`

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you be aware of the security risks here. If you really need to do this, add php to the group that owns that folder and use `664` rather than `777`

Comment: I'm doing testing on my local machine and changing the permissions of the `upload` folder was the fix that solved our teams issues for testing locally. Running `sudo chmod 777 ./<uploads folder>` allows for writing permissions from any user.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is late but it might help someone like it helped me

Just ensure you have given the user permission for the destination file

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /Users/George/Desktop/uploads/`

Comment: the same happened to me on Mac. I had to give permissions

Comment: @Thanks. its help me lot.

Comment: How often can I just kick myself. This is one of them. ty

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$ImageName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'file';
$path = 'Users/George/Desktop/uploads/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['file']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not refering to the *temporary location* where the file is saved.

Use `tmp_name` to access the file.

You can always see what's getting posted using :

```
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_FILES);
```

If you see this files array you will have an better understanding and idea of what's going on.

Comment: So what if print_r($_FILES) prints an empty array? I did the same as OP.

Comment: @Lewistrick it means that you might have forgot to mention the enctype attribute of form. Refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Answer (score 2):

it should like this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $move);
```

And you cannot move it anywhere in your system .youcan move it in only in your project directory which must be in htdocs or www depends on what you are using wampp ,lampp or vertrgo.

Comment: I'm using mamp and I tried with docs but it's still not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a windows machine, there won't be any problems with uploading or writing to the specified folder path, except the syntactical errors.

But in case of Linux users, there is a workaround to this problem, even if there are no syntactical errors visible.

First of all, I am assuming that you are using this in a Linux environment and you need to upload something to your project folder in the public directory.

Even if you are having the write and read access to the project folder, PHP is not handled by the end user. It is and can be handled by a `www-data` user, or group.

So in order to make this `www-data` get access
 first type in;

```
sudo chgrp "www-data" your_project_folder
```

once its done, if there is no write access to the following as well;

```
sudo chown g+w your_project_folder
```

That will do the trick in Linux.

Please, not that this is done in a Linux environment, with phpmyadmin, and mysql running.

Answer (score 1):

if files are not moving this could be due to several reasons

- check permissions that upload directory , make sure its permission is at least 0755.

> ```
> > find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # for directories find *
> > -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0666 # for files
> ```

- make sure upload directory owner & group is not root , in that case your script will not be able to write anything there, so change it to admin or any non-root user.

> ```
> chown -R admin:admin public_html      # will restore permission to admin  for folder and files within it 
> chown  admin:admin public_html      # will restore permission to admin  for folder only will skip files
> ```

- check your tmp directory that its writable or not so open php.ini and check upload_tmp_dir = your temp directory path , make sure its writable.
- try `copy` function instead of `move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake that I missed was not putting "enctype=multipart/form-data" as the element of the form. Just wanted to remind people because it might be your mistake

Answer (score 1):

always set folder directory properly for image otherwise image will not be upload check my code for image upload if you issue still there let me know will help you

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_picture']['tmp_name'],'../images/manager/'. 
    $_FILES["profile_picture"]['name'])) {
      echo "Uploaded";
} else {
      echo "File not uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **move_uploaded_file()** is not working for you and you are not getting any errors (like in my case), make sure that the size of the file/image you are uploading is not greater than **upload_max_filesize** value in **php.ini**.

My **upload_max_filesize** value was 2MB on my localhost and I kept trying to upload a 4MB image for countless times while trying to figure out what the issue with **move_uploaded_file()** is.

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)` **moves** the file, which means temp file/buffers will be cleared from original source. **move_uploaded_file()** is [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) aware. However, restrictions are placed only on the **to** path as to allow the moving of uploaded files in which **from path** may conflict with such restrictions.

`copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $to_path)`
When a file is **copied**, a duplicate is made means temporary buffers(source) is not cleaned. The **$to_path** should support overwriting of existing files.

Answer (score 0):

For me, php.ini "upload_max_filesize" was too small (updated now and it works).

Answer (score 0):

if you're working on centos greater than 6, you could check for sestatus....

if setenforce is 'enforcing' this might have repercussions on this PHP function, try with something like is_writeable('upload_dir'); to check if it's a writing permissions matter, and you can edit sestatus with>

setenforce permissive

this is one of many possible situations, like i said.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest Way to Uplaod a file

```
$FileName = $file_name;
$path = 'Users/Desktop/uploads/images'; 
$location = $path . $data['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($data['temp_name'],$location);
```