# Upload file selecting in Swing and sending via http post and save using a php script

Tags: php, swing, http-post

Using the http post via swing, and the URL as http://udaydungarwal.com/fileuploadhtml/upload.php , However, it does not receive the file on server. Can i get help please, The php script is:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fieldName"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fieldName"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fieldName"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fieldName"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fieldName"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you get a file upload successfully ***without*** using Swing?  If so, the PHP is irrelevant.  If not, remove the Swing tag.

Comment: 1. Check similar questions first, like: [Move_uploaded_file() function is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929178/move-uploaded-file-function-is-not-working). 2. Can you specify the target directory as an absolute path (like for example "/uploads/") instead of a relative path ("uploads/")? 3. Also, you could simplify the code: remove all checks and call the `move_uploaded_file` function with some fixed values that should work.

Comment: I want to select the file to be uploaded using a swing application and update that to the server using php