# move_uploaded_file returns error code 0 but file not uploaded in my directory?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm working on a project using codeigniter 3.0.6 and I need to upload image in some modules. the problem is that move_uploaded_file returns error code 0 but the file is nowhere to be found. I'm currently running this code on my localhost. if only it returns an error code then I can do something.. can anyone help me with this?

I've read [Move_uploaded_file() function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929178/move-uploaded-file-function-is-not-working) too and my code below is based on one of the supposedly "working example" answer.. but still not working (error code 0 but file not found in directory). the `mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);` part doesn't seem to help.

this is my view file (display.php) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="submit" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="51200000" />
            Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my controller file (test.php) :

```
function display()
{
    $this->load->view('display');
}

function submit() {
    $uploaddir = '/assets/img/guide/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
    } 

    echo "<p>";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed";
    }
    echo "</p>";

    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Error code:';
    print_r($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
    print "</pre>";     

    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";     

    echo $this->load->view('display', $this->data);
}
```

and this is the result after I submit the form:

> File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.
>
> Error code:0
>
> Here is some more debugging info:Array (
>       [userfile] => Array
>           (
>               [name] => Hydrangeas.jpg
>               [type] => image/jpeg
>               [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php46FD.tmp
>               [error] => 0
>               [size] => 595284
>           )
>
> )

Comment: Codeigniter has a nice upload library to use. Why dont you use it?

Comment: Don't get confused: that 0 comes from the upload preprocessor (`$_FILES['userfile']['error']`); `move_uploaded_files()` does not return any code but just a boolean (which appears to be `true` in your case). If there's an error in that phase, it'll show up as PHP warning.

Comment: Use do_upload() in CodeIgniter,

Comment: I used to code in flat php so I guess old habits die hard.. and also, I thought native php function such as move_uploaded_file is faster? I'll try to use do_upload to avoid wasting time, but still curious about this :P

@EvisBregu the assets folder is on my root directory

Comment: Is your upload folder correct? It seems that you are using an absolute path. Where is your assets folder physically, inside your web root folder or on your operating system root?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the files WERE uploaded but instead of going to my project's base folder (D:/myproject/dev/), the files were uploaded to the harddrive folder (D:/) so i guess the mistery's solved. I just need to figure out how to direct the target folder for upload.. maybe I'll put it in another question post.

thank you all