# php move_uploaded_file to custom folder

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to upload files into separate folders based on the variable in the URI:

i.e.:

http://example.com/upload.php?name=john

```
// set specific folder uploads
$destFolder = $_GET['name'];


// success
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$destFolder.'/'.$timestamp.'-'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
exit;
}
```

It uploads the file fine, but into "/uploads", not into "/uploads/john".

What am I overlooking? Thanks for looking.

Comment: I'de guess $destFolder is empty for some reason.  Try logging that value and see what you get.  Also, it is dangerous to use user input for specifying uploaded file destinations.

Comment: The folder exists and is writable. There will be only a few pre-existing folders. echo $_GET['name'] does return "john".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move\_uploaded\_file() function is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929178/move-uploaded-file-function-is-not-working)

Comment: can you output `'uploads/'.$destFolder.'/'.$timestamp.'-'.$_FILES['upl']['name']` ?

Comment: Yes, it outputs correctly, including my "john" subfolder.