# When I click the submit button it's loading but no error and also i'm not getting mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHP Email form with attachment not working by PHPMailer help me what I'm missing. Without form and PHP code it's working in localhost but when i merge with the form it's totally not working..

```
 <?php


    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'classes/config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $mat = $_POST['mat'];
    $res = $_POST['res'];
    $tech = $_POST['tech'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $content='<br><br>Name: '.$name.'<br>'.'<br>Mobile: '.$mobile .'<br>Material: '.$mat.'<br>Res: '.$res.'<br>tech: '.$tech.'<br>City: '.$city .'<br>Message: '.$message.'<br>Email: '.$email;

    $file_name = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $file_tmp = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $file_path = "upload";

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads" . $file_name)){

    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

        $mail->isSMTP();                                          
        $mail->Host       = Config::SMTP_HOST;                    

        $mail->Username   = Config::SMTP_USER;                     
        $mail->Password   = Config::SMTP_PASS;
        $mail->Port       = Config::SMTP_PORT;                               
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   
        $mail->isHTML(true); 
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->setFrom('mail');
        $mail->addAddress('mail');
        $mail->Subject = 'Got a Enquiry';
        $mail->Body    = $content;
        $mail->addAttachment($file_path, $file_name);

        if($mail->send()){

          echo 'Super';
        } else {

        echo 'nothing:' .$mail->ErrorInfo;

    }
    }
    }

    ?>



<form class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot; >

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bzd-upload-1-1">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 frm-bg">
                                <img src="img/upload-icon.png" class="img-responsive">
                                 <p>Drag and Drop Files<br/>
                        or Upload Here</p>
                          <p class="file">

                                    <label for="file_attach">
                               <h6>Browse</h6>
                            </label>
                            <input name="image" type="file" id="file" class="feedback-input">
                        </p>
                            </div>



                        </div>

                         <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bzd-form-1-1">


                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                            <label class="form-1-1">Name</label>

                        <p class="name">

                            <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Name" id="name" />

                        </p>
                             </div>


                       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">  
                           <label class="form-1-1">Email</label>
                        <p class="email">

                            <input name="email" type="email" required class="feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">     
                            <label class="form-1-1">Mobile No</label>
                        <p class="name">

                            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Phone" id="phone" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                             <label class="form-1-1">Material</label>
                         <p class="name">

                            <input name="mat" type="tel" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Material" id="mat" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">  
                             <label class="form-1-1">Resolution</label>
                         <p class="name">

                            <input name="res" type="tel" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Resolution" id="res" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">   
                            <label class="form-1-1">Technology</label>
                         <p class="name">

                            <input name="tech" type="tel" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Technology" id="tech" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">  
                            <label class="form-1-1">City</label>
                        <p class="name">

                            <input name="city" type="text" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="City" id="city" />

                        </p>
                             </div>

                       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group"> 
                           <label class="form-1-1">Message</label>
                        <p class="text">

                            <textarea name="message" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                        </p>
                             </div>

                              <div class="submit">
                            <button type="submit" class="button-blue">SUBMIT</button>
                            <div class="ease"></div>
                        </div>

                        </div>    

                    </form>
```

When I click the submit button it's loading... No error displayed and also i'm not getting mail. I am also search some more articles but still it is not resolved.. kindly help me in this..

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: Change your form line to this : `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` you dont have post method in your form, it doesnt post your values to php page, I just updated answer.if your php codes are not in same page! change this `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` to your page.php in action

Comment: `var_dump($file_name);` see if its not empty and correct your path `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads" . $file_name)){` and search for uploading files. here some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929178/move-uploaded-file-function-is-not-working

Comment: I corrected your upload codes in answer check down the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

but your form does not contain an input named `submit`, so this condition will never be true and your sending code will not be run.

You have this submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="button-blue">SUBMIT</button>
```

but it has no name or value attribute. Change it to this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button-blue">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Hi thank you... changed that also but no same problem persists

Comment: So check your input data containsall you expect - do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see.

Comment: Thank You!.. So Much.......

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `error_log` file it would show you whats going wrong.

Actualy `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` would create troubleshoots of errors too, so maybe your emails going to spam box.

Here is the code working on my localhost :

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);
//Or $mail = new PHPMailer; 
//Enable SMTP debugging. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
//Set $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; on live sites.                        
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "useremail@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "password";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
//$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;                         
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->From = "name@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

$mail->smtpConnect(
    array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => true,
            "verify_peer_name" => true,
            "allow_self_signed" => false
        )
    )
);
//This won't require any server settings on your localhost.

$mail->addAddress("Recepient@email.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Change credentials to yours, and see if your emails not going to spam box.

Change your form line to this : `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` you dont have post method in your form, it doesnt post your values to php page.

**NOTE :** if your php codes are not in same page! change this `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` to your `page.php` in action.

Change Your upload codes to :

```
$file_name = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
$file_tmp = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$file_path = "upload/";

if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_path.$file_name)){
```

Comment: Hi, i have make the change <form class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> but not working...

Comment: Did you try `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button-blue">SUBMIT</button>` whats being said in other answer ? do that and then try my answer. and what means not working ? do you get any error ? or what is in error_log file ? or what troubleshoot says ? see here for debug https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/12232340

Comment: Yes I have tried it & I'm not getting any error!.. The form simply loading & my inputs are in URL Like "(http://localhost/test/?image=3.JPG&name=Bala&email=krishnanbkcl%40gmail.com&phone=9940061266&mat=bihba&res=dv&tech=bebedb&city=bgb&message=bgbgbg&name=)"

Comment: did you check error log file ? put this on top of your page  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see usaqe here : https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting it should display errors now and please check your spam box.

Comment: Now I receive the mail except the attachment. The error is "(Could not access file: upload)"

Comment: You are uploading file to uploads diresctory! `if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads" . $file_name)){` and trying to access it from `$file_path = "upload";` your directories doesnt match both should be `upload` or `uploads` I dont know your correct path.

Comment: Hi, I have chamged the uploads to upload but still i'm not getting the attachment and also i have pasted error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I'm not getting any error but the attachment was not sending

Comment: Thank You So much I figured out the issue and solved now my form is working fine...

Comment: Glad you solved it Can you please check answer as accepted please, if it helped.

Comment: $file_name = ($_FILES['image']['name']);

$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$path = 'upload';

$file = $path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],  $file))     "Could pls help me in that my uploaded file not placed in 'upload ' folder instead that my uploaded file placed in main project folder.  $mail->addAttachment($file, $_FILES['image']['name']);

Comment: Don't disable TLS certificate verification, and especially don't advise others to do so. Google does not use invalid certificates, so if it's not validating, it's **your server that's at fault**, so you should fix that instead of making your application vulnerable to person-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: @Synchro *it's working in localhost* dont think I need ssl or auth for securing. also its commented *This won't require any server settings on your localhost* on localhost. and commented for tls too. but thanks for warning.

Comment: You're not sending to `localhost`, you're sending to `smtp.gmail.com`. You do most definitely need both encryption and authentication to send through gmail, and it's not commented out in the code you posted. Setting those options will suppress error messages due to verification failure, giving you the false impression that "it's working on localhost" - and that is a very bad thing to do as it undermines much of the point of using TLS in the first place.