# WAMP server does not allow uploading files (PHP applicatipn)

Tags: php, html, database, image, wamp

I am developing a mobile jquery application that uses HTML/CSS/PHP languages.
I am trying to upload image wither by storing image in the server or in a directory but in both cases the following statement does not run although the code is correct

$file = @$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ;

Should I change something in server configuration to be able to upload images ? or there is another reason to this problem ?

Please help me

Comment: How about trying $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];, without @?

Comment: I did but nothing have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code to find error

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: I tried it and this was the output : Array
(
) but what does that mean ?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php