# $_FILES returns empty result while File upload in blueimg

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, blueimp

I am using multiple file upload for this blueimp plugin [demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), [doc](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

They are given file upload by the AJAX file. But, I dont need to upload by Ajax.
I need **$_FILES** details in same page while form submitting.

I have tried following code:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">

            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button id='subtest' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>
   </form>
<script>
    $('#subtest').click(function() {

        $('#fileupload').submit();
    });
</script>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {

        print_r($_FILES);
    }
?>
```

I got following $_FILES result while submitting the form.

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )
```

I dont know why result become likes above.
(UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
Value: 4; No file was uploaded).

Help me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `name="files[]"` for `name="files"` the `multiple` attribute should hand it as an array for you

Comment: No the name="files[]" should be fine, I just checked and its working using the exact code.

Comment: @SparK the same result coming for $_FILES.

Comment: try to change the name of the field

Comment: @RakeshShetty it will only change the array key...

Comment: @RakeshShetty I have changed as 'name=filetest[]' result becomes Array ( [filetest] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )

Comment: So... you don't need AJAX upload, but you are using a plugin whose sole purpose is to provide AJAX upload functionality? "I don't need a hat, how can I make my hat go away?"

Comment: @Jon for TODO operation of client side.. please see the demo http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: CHeck if your form is having anything as name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" if so remove this this can create issues on upload if uploading size is more than specified one.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php, also check if some .htaccess is restricting it.

Comment: @CHeck there is no field in that name. Now i found out the problem is JS files affecting that. bcoz If i remove the form id 'fileupload' means, it works fine.

Comment: i see it may the JS lib is doing some sort of disabling the form by that id, try using some other id and use the JS submit. its definitely some other js getting triggered from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Just close your form tag and try again. following code works on my system

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="fileupload" action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">

            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button id='subtest' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**uploader.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {

        print_r($_FILES);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have updated but the same result occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code since you don't want to submit the form via ajax :-

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        print_r($_FILES);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">

            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <input id='subtest' name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>



  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 4 means UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE means 'No file was uploaded.' you have some problem in your javascript code you using. Check your JavaScript error?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because no file was uploaded. Check the permissions of your temp folder.