# PHP - $_FILES array is empty

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Yes, the `enctype` attribute is set. Other forms/form-hanlders work fine so the temp directory must be writable. I'm out of Ideas.

I checked the post values and `$_POST['file']` exists and contains the name of the file.

Here is my form and the PHP that handles it. What am I missing?

```
<form action='orl_ftp.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose File: </td>
            <td><INPUT type='file' id='file' name='file'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><INPUT type='submit' name='Submit' value='Process'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And the relevant PHP code. Note that the $_FILES array **is set**, it's just **empty**.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $upload_results = "";
    if(!isset($_FILES)){$upload_results .= "No files uploaded"; }
    if($upload_results == ""){

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_FILES);
        exit;

        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Could there be a conflict since you have named your file field with the same name as the id?

Comment: @PhilipG is that really a thing? Every file upload form I've ever built I just use `file` as both the name and id and it has always worked.. I'll try changing it tho, can't hurt..

Comment: What do you want from the file uploaded?

Comment: can you post the result of `var_dump($_FILES)` ??

Comment: I dont know, and don't think that schould be a reason for the files not beeing sent. But its bad practise and javascript surely doesn't like it!

Comment: I'm not quite grasping the question here. If nothing is uploaded, then you can't expect it to show anything. I don't see `move_uploaded_file` anywhere, so this tells me this is not full code. To add, you say "array". When dealing with arrays, and if you are, then this `name='file'` needs brackets `name='file[]'`

Comment: I'd suggest turning on error reporting and checking server log. Maybe the file is too large or something.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, it's not the full code. it's the code up until the error. anything after that is irrelevant. but it is the full code up until that point.

Comment: *"I checked the post values and $_POST['file'] exists and contains the name of the file."* It's not `$_POST['file']` you should be checking, it's `$_FILES['file']` - where are you checking for `$_POST['file']`? I see you're checking `$_FILES` in your `var_dump()` but not anywhere else.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah `array(0) {}`

Comment: Testing the code on my local PC shows the code working perfectly. So I guess there is something wrong in the script you are POST'ing to.

Comment: PHP has variables that control maximum upload size. Your web server has configuration that limits the maximum request size. You haven't posted a single thing about those two. I suggest you google about that.

Comment: is `file_uploads = On;` in php.ini?

Comment: Work through this check list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/930917

Comment: @N.B. The file I'm uploading is 11KB.. the default should suffice. It's not there because it's not necessary to change it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of (without seeing full code), is that your file/folder and the ??? variable(s) are not properly set, or not set, or a typo. @Adelphia - I can't keep commenting like this (or anyone else for that matter), I'm terrible at shooting Black golf balls at midnight while aiming for a black hole. Remember, `$File` is not the same as `$file`. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've done this 100 times before successfully. If it was an easy fix I wouldn't be asking for help :)

Comment: I don't mind helping, but when I don't see the full picture, I can't be of further help. Nothing personal, that's just "me". ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- I'm getting desperate. Here's a pastebin with the entire code. http://pastebin.com/0rWNw6Jh

Comment: Why do u have a self closed form? Other than invalid html that may be causing your issue, what's the use of an empty form?

Comment: in your `php_ini` check `file_upload` is on or not.. and also check `max_upload_size`...

Comment: @Adelphia I noticed in your pastebin file `<input type="file" name="filez" />` notice the `z`? Think that might have anything to do with it? Shouldn't that be `<input type="file" name="file" />` as you posted in your question, just without the `z`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 101:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />
                                                                 ^
```

This is causing  the issue, the browser it keeping this form open and therefore the missing `enctype` is the issue. Remove or close this form properly.

Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $upload_results = "";
    if(!isset($_FILES)){$upload_results .= "No files uploaded"; }
    if($upload_results == ""){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_FILES);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<form action='' method="post" />
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose File: </td>
            <td><INPUT type='file' id='file' name='file'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><INPUT type='submit' name='Submit' value='Process'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This will not post any files.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah, he did do before he edited the post. Why on earth would I have made that up?

Comment: No he isn't? theres no slash at the end of tag!

Comment: Yes I did before and realized that when I posted this, but I fixed it, and it's still broken.

Comment: besides, if that was the issue than my $_POST array would be empty too, which it's not.

Comment: @Adelphia, i've un-deleted my question and corrected it. I was right initially, but just not the right line as you didn't post all of the relevant code.

Comment: O my goodness I can't believe I sweated this for 2 hours looking in the wrong place for an error. Thank you so much and sorry to waste everyone's time :)

Comment: @Adelphia Paid off showing full code ;-) It's the little things that count. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple forms in the same script and so each of them needs the `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Also, it doesn't look like you close the first form and doing `<form ... />` is not valid html.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Basically if you have more than 1 form on the page, close them properly.