# $_FILES is empty after POSTing with python script

Tags: php, python

I have a python script that is supposed to upload a file to a php script.

Python

```
import requests

file={'file':('text.txt','hello')}

url='mywebsite.org/test.php


response = requests.post(url, files=file)
                              
print(response.text)
```

PHP

```
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES);
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

This is the response that I am getting to the python script:

> array(0) {
>
> }
>
> array(0) {
>
> }

However, when I try posting to http://httpbin.org/post,

I get

> ...
>
> "files": {
>
> > "file": "hello"
>
> },
>
> ...

Which seems to indicate that there is something wrong with my server. What might be the problem?

Comment: for one thing, you're missing a closing quote in your Python `url='mywebsite...` line

Comment: It'll be good if you can provide more server info. Did you check php.ini? Are you using any framework?

Comment: BTW, the httpbin website you mention in your post is cool:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is problem in you python code - currently you do not send file since it is not open. Suppose your `text.txt` contains `1234`. Posting it to http://httpbin.org/post like this:

```
import requests

file={'file':(open('text.txt','r').read())}

url='http://httpbin.org/post'

response = requests.post(url, files=file)

print(response.text)
```

We get follow response:

```
...
"files": {
    "file": "1234"
  },
...
```

If you want to add some extra parameters, you can do it like this:

```
values = {'message': 'hello'}
response = requests.post(url, files=file, data=values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but having tried this solution, I have found it still does not work.
The requests library offers the functionality of posting text as a file, e.g. when posting file={'file':('text.txt','hello')}, this sends a file named 'text.txt' that contains the string 'hello'. This is not the problem, as I can see that http://httpbin.org/post replies that I have in fact posted the file there.

Comment: You're right, I did not know about this feature of `requests` library. Both methods work on my server. Ok, what about these solutions?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php