# FileDrop.js & PHP resulting in empty $_FILES

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, filedrop.js

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/zbhj26x7/#base)

I'm using `filedrop.js` to create a file repository structure within my app. The above noted [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/zbhj26x7/#base) has all of the Javascript / jQuery / HTML and CSS code for this small module. While everything on the client end seems to be functioning properly (files can be DnD'd, progress bar acts correctly, console shows proper event triggers), the result on the server-side is always an empty `$_FILES` variable. My PHP (**ajax.receiveFile.php**) is as follows:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
ob_start();
$callback = &$_REQUEST['fd-callback'];
$job_id = &$_REQUEST['job_id'];
$subdir = &$_REQUEST['subdir'];
$j = loadJob($job_id);
$save_path = "D:\\JobFiles\\" . $j->gOrderNumber() . "\\" . $subdir . "\\";
if ( ($_FILES['fd-file']['size'] > 0) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name']) ) {
  $name = $_FILES['fd-file']['name'];
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name'], $save_path.$name)) {
    $j->addAttachment($subdir,$name);
    echo 'true';
  } else {
    echo 'false';
  }
}
ob_end_flush();
```

`FileDrop.js` seems to be doing what it is supposed to do, as shown here:

[image: Console snap of form and input for file]
[image: Console snap of files being processed via AJAX calls]

I read [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php) that using the same element `name` over multiple input types of "file" can cause errors but I'm not sure that is the case here. I have double- and triple-checked the permissions on both the `TEMP` and `TARGET` upload folders, I have confirmed that all PHP variables are set as needed via visual inspection and `PHPINFO()`. The server config is PHP 5.4 on IIS7.

If anyone has any ideas on what else to look for, please contribute. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, browser dont like similar call, maybe you could add an uniq value as ajax.receiveFile.php?subdir=drawing&job_id=6785&uniq=983 and increment/rand() uniq when you use upload multiples times.
file.sendTo('ajax/ajax.receiveFile.php?subdir=' + subdir + '&job_id=' + job_id + 'uniq='+ rand(0,1000) ); });

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. Besides, the Javascript syntax to generate a random number is `Math.random()`.

Comment: oops..
Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

Comment: My solution was to ditch *filedrop.js* and write my own routine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`file_put_contents('uploads/person/7.jpeg', fopen('php://input', 'r'));`