# File upload $_FILES array is empty

Tags: php, file

I want to upload a file to the server but the `$_FILES` array seems to empty.

Is there something wrong with my code below ?

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
                <table class='table table-striped table-hover'> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
                            Bestand(en)
                        </td>
                        <td> <input type='file' name='fotos[]' multiple='multiple' /> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td> Aangepaste bestandsnaam </td>
                        <td> <input type='text' name='naam' class='form-control' /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 

                        <td> <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Fotos toevoegen' name='fotos_toevoegen' /> </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
    if(isset($_POST['fotos_toevoegen'])){

    print_r($_FILES['fotos']['name']);

    $array_lenght = count($_FILES['fotos']['name']);
    //print_r($_FILES['fotos']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $array_lenght; $i++){

        $array_fotos = array();

        // trek $_FILES uit elkaar zodat je individuele foto kan toevoegen.
        foreach($_FILES['fotos'] as $key => $value){
            $array_fotos[$key] = $_FILES['fotos'][$key][$i];
        }



        $foto = new Foto();

        $foto->path = $path . '/cms/fotos/orginele-bestanden';
        $foto->naam = $_POST['naam'].'-'. $i;
        $foto->album_id = $session_album_id;
        $foto->file_info = $array_fotos;
        $foto->width_thumbnail = 300;
        $foto->height_thumbnail = 250;
        $foto->width_grootformaat = 500;
        $foto->height_grootformaat = 400;

        $foto->to_string();

        //$foto_beheer->add($foto);
    }


}
```

Print_r($_FILES['fotos']) shows me this: 
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => pannekoeken4.jpg [1] => pannekoeken5.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 6 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) )

Comment: Have you print like if(isset($_POST)){echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "</pre>";} As your code looks proper

Comment: why action is empty?

Comment: Please, add your PHP code too.

Comment: @ Bhumi Shah Yes id did, I did print_r($_FILES) that's how I found out it was empty.

Comment: leaving action empty send you back to the same page ( I know it's not a good practise )

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the size of the file uploaded against value configured for post_max_size

If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.

Please refer the following URL

[Click here](http://andrewcurioso.com/2010/06/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Some very basic testing gave me the following result:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_POST);
  var_dump($_FILES);
  echo '</pre>';
}


?>
<form action='testfile.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
                <table class='table table-striped table-hover'> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
                            Bestand(en)
                        </td>
                        <td> <input type='file' name='fotos[]' multiple='multiple' /> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td> Aangepaste bestandsnaam </td>
                        <td> <input type='text' name='naam' class='form-control' /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 

                        <td> <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Fotos toevoegen' name='fotos_toevoegen' /> </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["naam"]=>
  string(17) "customfilename"
  ["fotos_toevoegen"]=>
  string(15) "Fotos toevoegen"
}
array(1) {
  ["fotos"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(50) "2014-10-06.pdf"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php79bugX"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(770241)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not what is happening on my server, could it be that it's not my code but some server setting?

Comment: Have you checked this post already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: Ill check it out! If I find a solution, Ill post it here.