# $_FILES returns empty array, $_POST works fine

Tags: php, post

I'm using a Windows 8.1 system with Expressons Web 4, MySql, IE 11 and PHP 5.6.5.  I.m using the following code which is from a tutorial:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" name="testtext" />
    <br/>
        Select image to upload:
        <input type='hidden' name='maxfilesize' value='2000000'/>

    <input type="file" name="filename" id="fileToUpload" />

        <input type="submit" value="UploadImage" name="submit" />
     </form>
```

and this feeds upload.php:

```
    <?  
    echo '$_POST: ';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '<br/> $_FILES: ';
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo '<br/> Target_Directory: ';
    $target_dir = "../Home/";
    echo $target_dir . '<br/>' ;
    echo basename($_FILES["filename"]["name"]) . '<br/>';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
    echo $target_file . '<br/>' ;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo $imageFileType . '<br/>' ;
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } 
        else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
```

The $_POST and $_FILES arrays show as empty no matter what I try to upload.  Even a 10K .png file.  If I comment out the input with type = 'file', the $_POST array will be filled with the data from the first input.  If I leave it in, both arrays are empty no matter what I do.

My php.ini file has the following settings:

1. file_upload = On
2. upload_max_filesize = 4M
3. max_file_uploads = 20
4. post_max_size = 16M

I went through a 12 point check that is presented in another example but didn't see anything that was out of the ordinary.  I've review at least 50 other suggestions and haven't found anything that would resolve this.  It's probably something I'm overlooking but can't seem to find it.

No errors are posted in the log files relating to this problem.  They do work because other errors have shown in them.

Output showing both arrays empty:

```
$_POST: array(0) { } 
$_FILES: array(0) { } 
Target_Directory: ../Home/
Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\Users\EE\My Web Sites\timetubes\Home\upload.php on line 30 
Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\Users\EE\My Web Sites\timetubes\Home\upload.php on line 31 ../Home/
```

output with encoding type removed(enctype="multipart/form-data" removed from the form tag to demonstrate that pages do pass variables without the enctype):

```
    $_POST: array(4) { ["testtext"]=> string(4) "test" ["maxfilesize"]=> string(7) "2000000" ["fileToUpload"]=> string(71) "C:\Users\EE\My Web Sites\timetubes\images\skins\medieval\tube-ghost.png" ["submit"]=> string(11) "UploadImage" } 
    $_FILES: array(0) { } 
    Target_Directory: ../Home/
    Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\Users\EE\My Web Sites\timetubes\Home\upload.php on line 30 
    Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\Users\EE\My Web Sites\timetubes\Home\upload.php on line 31 ../Home/
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: they did match in the testing,  I overlooked that when posting this message thanks

Comment: And it redirects to upload.php and you clearly see that `var_dump($_FILES);` is empty ?

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see what comes of it. Also make sure that the folder you're wanting to upload to, has proper permissions set.

Comment: the arrays return nothing in the var_dump($_FILES) statement

Comment: Where's `move_uploaded_file()`? Without it, nothing gets uploaded.

Comment: It's farther down the script.  If the $_FILE array didn't show empty, I'm pretty sure the rest of the code would work properly.

Comment: Even before doing move_uplodaded_file() the $_FILES array should contain the temporal file

Comment: Try moving your `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` conditional further up. It seems that your PHP may not be processing anything outside that.

Comment: What permissions should be set in the folder I uploading to?  My user has full control as I am the administrator.

Comment: I had isset at the top but it kept dropping out of it because the array was empty

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: If I remove the encoding in the form header, the $_POST array starts working

Comment: @EricEndicott, I don't think this is directly related, but the permissions of the Apache user (usually www-data) are what matter when uploading and writing files.

Comment: Question edited to include errors messages.

Comment: Hmm, why does $_POST have the elements id as the array key for the file input field?

Comment: the example output you've posted is inconsistent with the provided code.

Comment: the first example reflects the output with the provided code.  The second output is what shows if I remove the enctype from the form tag which is included to show that the code does function without the encoding type.

Comment: Good question dan08.  It seems to read it as a text input without enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: But it should still use the name attribute as the array key.

Comment: I can't explain that one. Not sure why it is doing that.  Maybe you're on to something...

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php. I would be more help if you were using Linux.

Comment: You've got me some leads to check.  Thanks