# Cannot retrieve name, type and size of file in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve name, size, and type of file in php.
i have tried so many solution and made some of mine code but i m still not able to get those things. I ve googled and stackoverflow and did what they said but somehow its not done. I m sorry if i did any thing wrong but please help me.

This is my code.

```
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    try{
          if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newFilePath = "./filedata/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

        $target = "filedata/";
        $target = $target . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);

        echo "<br><br>file name :".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
        echo "<br>file size :".$_FILES['upload']['size'];
        echo "<br>file error :".$_FILES['upload']['error'];
        echo "<br>file type :".$_FILES['upload']['type'];
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
  } 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "There is an error : ". $e->error;
    }
}
```

And the output i got is

```
file name :Array
file size :Array
file error :Array
file type :Array
file title :
```

My HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="fileMaster.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload">
</form>
<a href="SimpleXMLElement.php"> Dynamic XML Link </a><br><br>
<a href="fileRead.php"> Demo File </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is anything displayed at all? If it doesn't, then I would say it doesn't go through the if-statement where you check $tmpFilePath != "" or the count is 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would $\_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

Comment: @Verkade89 above is the output i m getting. It is going in if part but i am not able to get that why output is like this. is it possible that i usee name in html file as name="upload[]"?

Comment: Oh wait, you need to add [$i] at the end of the variables. So $_FILES['upload']['name'] to $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]

Comment: @Verkade89 it works, thanks a ton man. (y).

Comment: @zilongqiu i m not sure but is most probably its not, because the problem i was getting is i was not able to get any details of the files, but its now solved.