# Invalid File on file upload PHP

Tags: php, html

***upload_file.php***

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma", "MP4");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

***html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

So my problem is I get the message "Invalid File". This only happens when I try to upload video type files. However when I try to upload an image it works like a charm. I've searched all over stackoverflow for other video file upload codes and still couldn't find any that worked. Anyone that could refer another question/solution to me and/or fix this problem will greatly be appreciated.

**EXTRA NOTE**
I've already tried adding `echo "Its type is " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];` to debug what file type is being given however it just returns a nice white space.

Comment: @SuchitKumar I'll check it out.

Comment: @SuchitKumar I don't understand their documentation. It redirects me to a page http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/open-source/index.html and I don't even know what to press.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part

```
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

to

```
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  echo "Its type is " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
  }
```

Now upload the files that don't work and add those types to your list

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that I've tried that already and it doesn't return anything. IT returns 'blank space'.

Comment: try doing `print_r($_FILES)` in the else part.

Comment: it returns `Array( )`

Comment: Try reading this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php It may have something to do with the size of the video files that you are trying to upload

Comment: Yeah I found the problem it was due to the php.ini low max_size value. IT was set to 10M. But thanks for the help anyways. I'll give you a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem only was because the php.ini was set to only accept 10M the file I was uploading was over 15MB and so I guess it gave me the error. But shouldn't that give me the error file-size is too much or something? But that's basically the reason I got the error. :)