# Magnento module file upload not working

Tags: magento, file-upload, magento-1.9

have a Magento module that takes an input and creates a new item off that input. Everything works fine, and I wanted to add a field that would input an image with the item. I made sure to add the corresponding database column, and made sure to make the change every where it would be needed, but when i upload an image through the new input the image field does not send in my post data. I still get an object with all the fields and values from my form but the File field is always omitted. Using `$_FILE` to try to access it yields nothing also.

Here is the form:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('embroidery_id' =>    $this->getRequest()->getParam('embroidery_id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'general',
        array(
            'legend' => $this->__('Details')
        )
    );
```

And here are the fields:

```
 $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'name' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Name'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'file_t' => array(
            'label'     => $this->__('File path'),
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => 'disable',
            'input'     => 'file',
            'name'      => 'file_t',
            'value'  => 'file_t',
        ),
    ));
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. i already did some googling and looked at all the top results for adding in a file upload field, and I copied some of the code exactly but the post field for the file input is still empty.

For Clarification:

The `_addFieldsToFieldset` function just loops through the fields array and either fills them in with data or adds the field onto the `$fieldset` variable. I also tried adding the field straight onto the variable with the following code but it did not work also.

```
$fieldset->addField('file_t', 'file', array(
      'label'     => $this->__('File path'),
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'file_t',
));
```

Here is the function that handles the saving. This function does work, it has been tried and tested multiple times when I submitted other forms, and all the fields were successfully saved, and everything was sent through, but whenever I add the file field on, the post data looks exactly the same, and everything still works, it just does not send the file field through the post.

```
       if(isset($_FILES['file_t']['name'])){
            echo 'TRUE';
        }

        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost()); exit();

        $em->addData($postData);
        $em->save();

        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
            $this->__('The embroidery has been saved.')
        );

        // redirect to remove $_POST data from the request
        return $this->_redirect(
        'mu_em_admin/embroidery/edit', 
            array('embroidery_id' => $em->getID())
        );
```

I simplified alot of the code down to only include the important parts. I also have the `var_dump` function there to troubleshoot the code. The results of `var_dump` were the whole post array that was sent, except for the file field.

Comment: You have special type of field for images that is called `imagefile`. I don't think it comes from that but the field is more appropriate. Can you show all the block class and the saving logic ?

Comment: I tried the `imagefile` field and it yielded the same results. in the end the field will be used for more than images so I'm using file, but just using Images to test. I'll add in the saving logic and block class stuff that's related to it, I'm current'y using `var_dump` to see the contents of the file field because I know the saving logic works fine because all my other form stuff from other tries were saved

Comment: is your PHP the Suhosin version?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't

Answer (score 0):

please try to put this form before body end and then submit.

what web browser do you use, and which version of php?

Comment: As in Form body do you mean adding in a form to the layout? I would rather not go that route and just use implement magentos framework and add my fields in using the form classes. And I'm using chrome or firefox, php version, not sure at the moment

Comment: If I remember correctly firefox had problems with submitting form if this is not placed in the code - IE as well.

Comment: also, hope you don't send this form trough ajax - files cannot be send trough ajax in a simple way

Comment: I'm 90% sure magento posts it to my edit page URL, it looks like it's not doing any Ajax requests or anything, looks like it just submits the form to the url