# Issue uploading file via PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981045/3943162) to upload a file via Ajax and PHP using Jquery, but it isn't working.

This is (part of) my HTML form (I'm using bootstrap):

```
<form  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit-company" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                     <label for="field-name-company">Name:</label>                 <input id="field-name-company" name="nameCompany" class="form-control" type="text"/> 
                 </div>
                 </div>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                             <label for="field-street-social-emp">Street</label>                   <input id="field-street-social-emp" name="streetCompany" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                     <div class="row">
                         <label for="foto-empresa">Foto/Logo:</label>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="file" name="fotoEmpresa"/>
                         </div>
                         <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="Confirm" id="submit-edit-company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Update</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

This is my jquery snippet:

```
$('#submit-edit-company').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formToSubmit = $(this).parents('form#edit-company');
        var dataToSend = formToSubmit.serialize();
        var fileInput = formToSubmit.find('input[type="file"]')[0];
        var fileData = fileInput.attr('files')[0];
        console.log(fileData);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'app/editCompanyService',
            data: dataToSend,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (return) {},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
            }
```

When I'm debugging the javascript and monitoring `fileInput`, I can see the file like `Files: FilesList[1] 0: File...`, but the script just stops and don't show anything in the console, even errors.

The `$_FILES` var in PHP is just empty. (All configurations pointed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/3943162) already checked).

Also tried `fileInput.prop('files')[0];` and `new FormData(formToSubmit)`, but I'm having the same problem.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Are you sure the browser you're using supports what you're trying to do?

Comment: @u_mulder. I did not see this question. I'll try the proposed solution to see if the problem is the same.

Comment: @Terminus. I think so. I'm using Firefox 42, and I'm not seeing any uncommon resource. Do you see?

Comment: Just noticed: if you're doing this `formToSubmit.find('input[type="file"]')[0];` you get back a regular dom element reference yet you do `fileInput.attr('files')[0];` on the next line. .attr is a jQuery function. Do `$(fileInput).attr('files')[0];`

Comment: The question sent by @u_mulder does not looks like the same problem, but help me to solve the problem. With `var dataToSend = new FormData(formToSubmit[0]);` all works fine.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although is not the same problem, the answer for [this SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) (linked in the question comments by @u_mulder) solves my problem.

Here is the functional code:

```
$('#submit-edit-company').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formToSubmit = $(this).parents('form#edit-company');
        var dataToSend = new FormData(formToSubmit[0]);
        var fileInput = formToSubmit.find('input[type="file"]')[0];
        var fileData = fileInput.attr('files')[0];
        console.log(fileData);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'app/editCompanyService',
            data: dataToSend,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (return) {},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
            }
```