# PHP file upload always returns an error

Tags: php, forms, upload

I've tried heaps of different things to get my php file upload to work, even trimming it right back to the absolute basics. I've tried different scripts and this and that but it's still giving me errors.

So I have this php script:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $target_path = "uploads/";
   $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
   } else {
      echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
   }
}
```

So as you can see, absolute bare minimum. This is my simple HTML form:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadform" method="post" >
   <input size="10" style="border:0px;" name="uploadedfile" type="file">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttonUpload" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Any file I try and upload gives me the error. This isn't the first piece of code I've tried. I tried the code example of w3schools, that again gave me the file upload error.

I've checked my php.ini and allow file uploads is on.

It's on my local machine so no need to chmod the upload folder.

Any suggestions on why this may be happening ?

Cheers!

Comment: *"but it's still giving me errors"* - Being what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, error may be the wrong word. It's returning the "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!". There's no specific php error or entry in my error log.

Comment: what about to display `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: That doesn't display any errors. Still just echo's what is above.

Comment: you on * NIX or Windows, other? xampp/wamp/mamp? if you made any changes to system files and didn't restart all services, that could be it. *"It's on my local machine so no need to chmod the upload folder."* - Hm, you sure about that?

Comment: I'm running UniServerZ on Windows. I've restarted all services and it's still producing the above. I don't understand what the issue is!

Comment: The `move_uploaded_file` can fail for a lot of reasons. Are you sure the target directory is writable? You can use `is_writable()` to test.

Comment: Yes, the target directory is writable. Just used is_writable() to test.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($_FILES); exit;` before this code and make sure it contains what you think it does?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please Jeremy?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to check things and debug a problem. One of the simplest is to use the `var_dump()` function and pass it a variable to see the contents. You would usually follow it with an `exit;` statement so that the code doesn't continue execution. The result is the variable contents gets dumped to your screen. It lets you make sure a file is in the $_FILES array to rule out a form issue, or make sure paths are correct. You can dump your `$target_path` and make sure that it is correct also for example.

Comment: Very interesting. It looks like it's returning an empty array `array(0) { }`

Comment: have a look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Have looked through all of those suggestions and all his suggestions I am doing. Cheers.