# how to upload multiple image file in one transaction using php and mysqli?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, input-type-file

I'm trying to insert multiple images in database per transaction, but each image has its own input types. But when I submit the form, I get the error that my `$file_upload = $_FILES['file_upload'.$i];` from my post.php is an "undefined index" . Are  the `file-upload1`, `file-upload2`, `file-upload3` from my HTML are not the correct way to do this? Please help. Thank you.

My php code is:

```
include 'dbcontroller.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $file_upload = $_FILES['file_upload'.$i];

        $file=(rand(1000,100000)."-".$file_upload['name'.$i]);
        $type=$file_upload['type'.$i];
        $size=$file_upload['size'.$i];
        $loc=$file_upload['tmp_name'.$i];

        $new_size=$size/1024; // file size in KB

        // make file name in lower case
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        // make file name in lower case

        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

        if(move_uploaded_file($loc, '..admin/officers-avatars/'.$final_file)) {
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO images VALUES ('$final_file', '$new_size', '$type')")
            or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my HTML

```html
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multiple/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file-upload1" /><br><br>
 <input type="file" name="file-upload2" /><br><br>
 <input type="file" name="file-upload3" /><br><br>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` on `$_FILES` to see what's actually there?

Comment: No,I haven't. And haven't tried `var_dump` before, but I'll  give it a try. @EatPeanutButter

Comment: Did it. And I got a NULL . Wew @EatPeanutButter

Comment: That means your files aren't being uploaded to the server correctly. If @filippe's suggestions do not work, see this checklist of things that could be going wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: Thanks. That link actually helped me. @EatPeanutButter

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: Change `enctype="multiple/form-data"` for `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Anyway, I would suggest you to use an array in `name` attribute instead:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>
```

Then in PHP you use this:

```
foreach($_FILES['fileupload'] as $file) {
    ....
}
```

Or you can use multiple:

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple /><br><br>
```

Comment: I would suggest using  `<input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple />`, but be careful what you allow your users to upload directly into your database, you could get some harmful viruses uploaded onto your site and not know how or where they came from.

Comment: Also, check the enctype part.. you need to use `multipart` instead of `multiple`

Comment: i tried your code but i'm having an error. `Notice: Undefined index: fileupload` and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` both on the same line. and thanks for noticing my typo error :)

Comment: I've found the exact error I had, it was just only that my file's name in my HTML is not the same with my php that's why I'm getting an undefined error. Fixed it and working now. Your answer was useful tho, thanks.