# $_FILES does not works when uploading video or audio using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying upload audio and video files using php. In my local server `$_FILES` variable does not work when i'm uploading audio or video files, however the same code properly working when uploading any kind of image. I'm checking the code in simple fresh file. `(I didn't include anything in this file like js, css or any php class etc)`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
}
<form action="fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Code is in the same file `fileUpload.php`.  i followed steps of this [**answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php) and also update wamp server memory according this [**forum**](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,28660,81982) instructions.

Can anyone guide me what is issue that i can resolve it. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You So Much.

Comment: Check sizes of your files.

Comment: if you echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] what you get?

Comment: @u_mulder `audio` file size is `4MB` and `video` file size is `14MB`

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Nothing when uploading `audio` or `video` file

Comment: ok try this --> if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would $\_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I know that, that'swhy i mention same link in my question. I followed the instruction but still facing same issue.

Comment: Right. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what they are already set to, try increasing one or both of these in your php.ini

post_max_size

upload_max_filesize

Answer (score -2):

I think it's not the code itself. I tried your example and it works.
Just added the php tags to your example, but i suppose that you have them in your exapmle.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
  }
?>
<form action="fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

running it got

```
Array ( [name] => WP_20150614_19_03_18_Pro.mp4 [type] => video/mp4 [tmp_name] => C:\ctt\tmp\phpF707.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 5804361 )
```

Comment: Thanks for interest, I know php code can't execute without php tags, I already added in my file.