# PUT upload does not fill $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, dropzone.js

I'm using PUT method to upload files using dropzone.js on frontend. However when I want to work with files both Symfony's `Request` object and `$_FILES` array are empty.

I have checked everything in [this huge checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/2876791) and it did not help to me since it does not says anything about uploading via PUT method.

Comment: Line one of the description from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). `An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the **HTTP POST** method.` emphasis added.

Comment: I found it in the documentation and this is the reason why I replied to my own question. Link added in description for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would $\_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not convert files uploaded via `PUT` method into `$_FILES` hence Symfony`s `Request` object is empty too.

You need to handle incoming file using following code.

```
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
```

Or using `$request->getContent()` in symfony.

> PHP also supports PUT-method file uploads as used by Netscape Composer
>   and W3C's Amaya clients. See the [PUT Method Support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for more details.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Why are asking and answering your question at the same time? So you knew the obvious answer for a simple question? What's the point?

Comment: I think it can help to someone in the future since StackOverflow became resource of knowledge.

Comment: yeah it is helping me now