# $_FILE is not working on new server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, image-uploading

I am facing the weird problem of image uploading. Currently we have changed our server and domain of the project, in which everything is working on php Codeigniter, once we shifted our project to the new server the **$_FILE['imageName']** is not working on the new server and it is showing the null value inside of $_FILE['imageName']. I think it's some settings issue that's why file data is not uploading and not showing inside of $_FILE['imageName'] and it was 100% working fine on our previous server. Can anybody help us for getting rid of this issue. Thanks :)

[Image: Error Message on new server against $_FILE['imageName'] and Null data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpMua.png)

[Image: In our old server $_FILE['imageName'] is showing data 100% fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwREL.png)

**This is the code on both files:**

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_FILES['imageName']);
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="imageName" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i dont get it, in your new server image (first one) are you choosing any file and submitting? or submitting blank ?

Comment: I am submitting the image. It's the output after submitting the image.

Comment: is  `file_uploads` directive enabled in your php settings?

Comment: Yes it's enabled. I checked it from <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: how about dumping only $_FILES ? is it also null?

Comment: Yes it's outputting null value: array(0) { }

Comment: You have left your action blank try use codeigniter form helper `form_open_multipart('controller/function')` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: Here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#creating-the-upload-form and here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller

Comment: Currently i am running this script on php so there is no need to add the file helper as it is running fine on old server without this helper.

Comment: I think it's some setting problem of the server or in php.ini but i don't have any knowledge of server settings and php.ini :(

Comment: Did you add all libraries which you added to previous server?
And also did you change read write permissions to file uploaded folder?

Comment: 1 thing is new in our new server is that it's now the https server. Is it causing the issue?

Comment: Yes all libraries are present as like in old.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check on server GD library is installed or not. i think you need to install GD library

Comment: GD Support:enabled     ,  GD headers Version:2.2.4      , GD library Version:2.2.4

Comment: I have solved this problem by removing the .htaccess file contents who was restricting the filesize and other file relating things.