# Upload a File PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I am trying to upload images to a MySQL database using the LAMP stack.

**HTML form:**

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label>File: </label>
     <input type="file" name="image">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

**PHP script:**

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo $_POST["submit"];
    var_dump($_FILES);
  }

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "users";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  session_start();

  $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
  $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `userprofile` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
  if (!$conn->query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
  }

  session_destroy();

?>
```

I got the following warning:

> Undefined index: image in /upload.php

I have tried everything in the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php#_=_)

This includes setting permissions on `upload_tmp_dir` and making sure `file_uploads` is on.

Comment: Try checking `$_FILES['image']['error']` and also check out [the manual for uploading files in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly.  I incorporated the error checking code.  It seems that $_FILES does not exist.  When I click submit, the $_FILES variable doesn't contain any data.

Comment: I was using JQuery Mobile.  You have to set data-ajax="false" http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/forms/#FileInputsAjax