# $_FILES is empty in form

Tags: php, html

I have the following form which sends its data to a php file which then processes the data and emails it to me. The problem is that I'm trying to upload a document along with the multipart form and it's not working. It sends the email just without the attachment. The weird thing is it used to work, but I'm not sure what I changed. `$_FILES` in the PHP form is always empty now, which suggests a problem with my html and not the PHP. I have been through the possible solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/362840) link, but none of them worked for me. Can anyone see what's wrong with this form?

```
<form id="pre-register-contact-form" action="preregisterform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name*</label>
          <input required="required" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" data-error="Please make sure you've entered your name.">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="age">Age</label>
          <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Enter your age">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address*</label>
        <input required="required" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your email address" data-error="Please make sure you've entered your email address.">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
        <small id="phoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your phone number with anyone else.</small>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Add anything extra that you'd like to tell us about yourself here." rows="3"></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cv">Upload CV*</label>
        <input required="required" name="cv" type="file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" class="form-control-file" id="cv" data-error="Please make sure you've uploaded a CV.">
        <small id="cvHelp" class="form-text text-muted" aria-describedby="cvHelp">Please make sure it is in PDF or Word format.</small>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcxSDgUAAAAAEM5qhjSDGS-Vu9HJSzLiL7yaAIG"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

My PHP file is as follows (sensitive info removed):

```
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('../elements/recaptcha/recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once('../elements/mail/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('../elements/mail/Exception.php');
require_once('../elements/mail/SMTP.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// configure

$sendTo = 'an_email_address_here';
$subject = 'New Pre-Register Contact Form Email';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'age' => 'Age', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'comments' => 'Comments', 'cv' => 'CV'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. We will be in touch when the right vacancy for you comes up.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error submitting the form. Please make sure your details are correct and try again.';
$recaptchaSecret = 'Some_alphanumeric_value_here';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception, 
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key in the config above 
        // from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually




        //Server settings
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'some_email_address_here';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'a_password';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to




        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom("an_email_address", "Some_Name");
        $mail->addReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
        $mail->addAddress('an_email_address', 'some_name');     // Add a recipient

            // This bit is always false
            if (array_key_exists('cv', $_FILES)) {
                $file_type = $_FILES['cv']['type'];
                if (($file_type != 'application/pdf' || $file_type != 'application/msword')) {
                    throw new \Exception("Please make sure you are only uploading a PDF or a Word document.");
                }
                $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['cv']['name']));

                $file_name        = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
                $file_size        = $_FILES['cv']['size'];

                $file_error       = $_FILES['cv']['error'];

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                    $mail->addAttachment(
                        $uploadfile,
                        $file_name,
                        'base64',
                        $file_type
                    );
                }
            }

            $emailText = "";

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                    $emailText .= "<b>$fields[$key]:</b> $value<br>";
                }
            }

            $emailText .= "<br><br><span style=\"font-size: 12px; color: grey;\">Email sent via the careers pre-register contact form.</span><br>";

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $emailText;
        $mail->AltBody = $emailText;

        $mail->send();
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

**EDIT**

Just remembered I am using AJAX with the form! Here is the JQuery, I think this is causing the problem:

```
$('#pre-register-contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "preregisterform.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($_FILES) in your php?

Comment: then show us the backend side where you wrote code for sending mail

Comment: @LioraHaydont yeah it says `array(0) { }`

Comment: @CavidKərimov Updated!

Comment: @Tometoyou maybe you have some permissions problem, have you checked the PHP configuration ("file_uploads", "max_file_uploads", "upload_tmp_dir")

Comment: do you use ajax ?

Comment: @MauricioFlorez I can't change them because of using shared hosting however, it worked before so I don't think it's that.

Comment: @CavidKərimov nope

Comment: Can you check your post in Chrome or Firefox in a console -> Network tab? This can help you https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=es

Comment: @MauricioFlorez Just had a look, it doesn't seem to attach the file to the form! Doesn't even seem to recognise the input...

Comment: ok, did you var_dump($_FILES). What it shows ? I think it should be there.

Comment: @CavidKərimov I already did that, see comments above

Comment: Hm... very strange, code seems ok, maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: I tried your code and had the same result as you, but doing more test I found the problem was the size of the uploaded file, a file with a few Kb was loaded. Can you verify the size of upload files (upload_max_filesize) in the PHP configuration?

Comment: @MauricioFlorez Really, let me try that with a smaller file. I was only uploading 64kb.. And I'm using Site Ground as my hosting provider with a fixed size of 128MB so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @MauricioFlorez I tried with 11kb... nothing...

Comment: @CavidKərimov I've just remembered I am using Ajax. I've updated my question, I think this is where the problem lies!

Comment: I supposed it. Wait a minute I will write the answer to your question @Tometoyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload a file with ajax you should use Formdata like this:

```
$('#pre-register-contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var this = $(this);
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "preregisterform.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType:'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
```

[You can find more detailed information here about how to send/upload files with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: This works! Although this doesn't seem to put the message text in the same page as the form. It just displays it on a new page. Before adding the FormData() stuff it would display the success message in the 'messages' div. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Because I added dataType: json . You shoul encode response on backend side. And in ajax success, fail etc you should parse returning json response