# Copy a multiple file from client system to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, form-data

I don't have any idea to copy a file from client system to server.
Short Description

- I am using upload folder dialog box to upload a multiple file from particular path.
- XML file is mandatory, because i need to extract some information to process
- While upload event i read all the information i need to process

  ```
  $("#myInput").change(function() {
  var names = [];
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i)
  {
  var F_name= $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
  var extension = F_name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
  if(extension != "xml" && extension != "db"){
  formData.append('userfiles[]', $(this).get(0).files[i], F_name);
  }
  else if(extension == "xml"){    
  //Gathering info
  }}    });
  ```

  User interface fields are filled automatically after this process and user have to fill some more fields. While user click process button in server side i create folder and some new XML files too. Everything is fine except , copy a file from client to server.

//Jquery

```
$("#process_but" ).click(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Asset/PHP/function.php",
data: {action: "action1", DOI:doi, TLA:tla, STITLE:S_Title, SHEAD:S_Head, SLINK:S_Link, LTYPE:link_type, DESC:description, ATITLE:Art_title, JTitle:JOU_title, ANAME:Author_name, FSHARE:Fig_share, FNAMES:filenames, FCOUNT:filecount},
success: function(response) {                       
if(response == 1)
{alert("success");}
else
{alert("Something goes wrong.....");}
},
error: function() {
alert("Error");
}
});
});
```

//php

```
<?php
session_start();
$action = $_POST['action'];
if($action == "action1")
{
//what i have to do
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would $\_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

Comment: i post my code and explain the way i used. but i don't know how to append to my current code

Comment: formData.append('userfiles[]', $(this).get(0).files[i], F_name); is this any use to store my file. how can i transfer files via ajax?????