# PHP upload image -> Undefined index

Tags: php, forms, image, upload

I'm trying to do a form to upload a image to a folder on the root directory of the domain '/uploads' and the information to a database (doing that after solving this problem). But everytime I try to submit the data, the upload PHP prints this:

> Array
>   (
>   )
>   files exist
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: profileUpload in [my pc directory to host]/data/db-updates/addAccount.php on line 29
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: profileUpload in [my pc directory to host]/data/db-updates/addAccount.php on line 30
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: profileUpload in [my pc directory to host]/data/db-updates/addAccount.php on line 31
>
> Sorry your file was not uploaded

I'm currently developing the website that contains this page on MAMP (mac).

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
```

admin-addAccount.php (file with form)

```
<?php
  //ini_set("display_errors","on");
  //error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/data/css/admin-addAccount.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/beon" type="text/css"/>
<section class="content">
  <div class="addAccount_holder">
    <div class="addAccount_holder_title">Adicionar Conta</div>
    <div class="addAccount_holder_content">
      <form action="/data/db-updates/addAccount.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="profileUpload" id="profileUpload" class="profileUpload" />
        <label for="profileUpload"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Foto de Perfil</label><br />
        <span>Nome</span><input name="nome" type="text" required/><br />
        <span>Email</span><input name="email" type="email" required/><br />
        <span>URL</span><input name="url" type="text" required/><br />
        <span>Instagram</span><input name="instagram" type="text" /><br />
        <span>Facebook</span><input name="facebook" type="text" /><br />
        <span>Twitter</span><input name="twitter" type="text" /><br />
        <span>Telemóvel</span><input name="telm" type="text" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

addAccount.php (file that does the upload and the rest)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (TRUE) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_FILES);
  echo '<pre>';
}

$ok = TRUE;

// Check if there is an uploaded file.
if (!array_key_exists('profileUpload', $_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['profileUpload'])) {
  echo "Sorry, no file seems to be uploaded.";
  $ok = FALSE;
} else {
  echo "files exist";
}

$charactersId = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$charactersLength = strlen($charactersId);
$userid = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) { $userid .= $charactersId[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; }

$target = "/uploads/";
$target = $target . 'usrProfile_'.$userid.$_FILES['profileUpload']['type'] ;
$uploaded_type = $_FILES['profileUpload']['type'];
$uploaded_size = $_FILES['profileUpload']['size'];

// This is our size condition.
if ($uploaded_size > 350000) {
  echo "Your file is too large.<br>";
  $ok = FALSE;
}

//This is our limit file type condition
if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") {
  echo "No PHP files<br>";
  $ok = FALSE;
}

// Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error
if ($ok) {
  echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded";
}
// If everything is ok we try to upload it
else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileUpload']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['profileUpload']['name']). " has been uploaded";
  }
  else {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
  }
}

?>
```

I've already searched here on stack overflow and the only solution that i found was including `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but I've already had that and it keeps showing me the errors.

[edit 1: added names to inputs]

Comment: Your `<input>` elements need `name` attribute so you can refer to them in php:
`<input type="text" name="somename"/>`

Comment: it still gives me the same error @user3647971

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php Check this one out, I'm sure there's your solution :) cheers

Comment: I've check that and my php.ini complies with the settings on the post you linked and the rest, as I can see, also follows everything there... @user3647971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem! Removed the '.php' extension the form action.

Now I have it like this:

```
<form action="/data/db-updates/addAccount" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```