# Unable to send a file from nodejs app to a php endpoint

Tags: php, node.js, axios, form-data

I am trying to send a zip file from my nodejs app to an endpoint written in PHP.
I am using axios and formdata

here is my js code:

```
        const endpoint = '...';
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath), zipFileName);
        axios
            .post(endpoint, form, {
                headers: form.getHeaders()
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

I am not getting the file at the php side, $_FILES is always empty.

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

var_dump($_FILES);
die('response from server');
```

Comment: And `FormData` comes from.... https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data ?

Comment: yes, `const FormData = require('form-data');`

Comment: Why not just use the [`submit()`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#request-submit-params-function-callback-) method? There's also specific [Axios](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#axios) instructions which look slightly different to what you have regarding `headers` (though I can't think why that would make a difference)

Comment: Can you show your PHP code? How are you actually verifying that `$_FILES` is empty? When and where do you see that?

Comment: added my php code to the description above. in js I am printing the response from endpoint and it shows me: `array(0) {} response from server`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Have you checked this article ~ https://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php. There are many config properties that effect your ability to handle file uploads in PHP

Comment: See if this solves your problem ~ [Why would $_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php) (ignore the HTML parts obviously)

Comment: thanks alot @phil, the link in your last comment was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, it was a php ini issue. Added a .user.ini file and added settings for upload vars.
all works now, thanks all.

here are my settings:

```
[PHP]
default_charset = "UTF-8"
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 20
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 180
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

Comment: In order to make this answer actually useful, please provide the settings you added

Comment: added my ini settings to my answer